# How should I fetch the array from firestore database in flutter?

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch arrays from the firestore database, but not able to do so

I am fetching other fields as this

```
return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            String itemTitle = snapshot.data.documents[index]['itemTitle'];
            String Name = snapshot.data.documents[index]['name'];
           
            return ListCard(Name: Name,itemTitle: itemTitle,);

          });
```

The array I want to fetch is in this screenshot

[image: screenshot]

How should I get it?

Answer (score 1):

For a single value

```
String steps = snapshot.data.documents[index]['steps'][0]['step']
```

or you can iterate

```
List steps = [];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        steps.add(snapshot.data.documents[index]['steps'][i]['step'])
     }
```

Comment: will it fetch whole list of the array or one particular element? I need to fetch all elements in one go

Comment: the second one will fetch each item and store a list of strings

Comment: In addition: if the number of steps is unknown at compile time: `for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents[index]['steps'].length; i++) ...`

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all steps as a list, try this

```dart
return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            String itemTitle = snapshot.data.documents[index]['itemTitle'];
            String Name = snapshot.data.documents[index]['name'];
            List steps = List.castFrom(snapshot.data.documents[index]["steps"]); //this
            return ListCard(Name: Name,itemTitle: itemTitle,);

          });
```